# Why does ELF file have so many blank spaces?

Tags: linux, elf, sparc

I'm sorry about the weird snippets. I won't be able to paste the exact code.

The following list from an ELF file shows addresses and commands at them.

```
    0x4000XXXX:     [someInstr] [someReg], [someReg2], [someReg3]
    0x4000XXXY:     [someInstr] [someRegValue], [somereg3]
    0x4000XXXZ:     [jumpInstruction] [someReg3] + 0xXXX, [someReg4]
    0x4000XXXA:     [someInstr]
    0x4000XXXB:     [someInstr]
    0x4000XXXC:     [someInstr]
    0x4000XXXD:
```

The third instruction adds `0xXXX` [which is some address value] to value in `someReg3` register. Going there,

```
    0x4000YYYY:     [someInstruction]
    0x4000YYYZ:     [someInstruction]
    0x4000YYYX:     [someInstruction]
    0x4000YYYA:
```

we see that the execution will stop once `0x4000YYYA` address comes up as it is blank. [The instructions above it are all linear ones like OR, AND etc.]

My question is, **why are the blanks even there?**

In the example I gave above, I have no idea where the exact "ending" instruction resides, but using `nm -S [filename]` and `readelf -l [filename]` I was able to estimate 2 end points. Unfortunately, those addresses have unimplemented instructions and it causes interruptions in the program. The file has quite a lot of blank spaces but I've only included 2 for an example. These blanks are interrupting the program I'm running. Even if I skip the execution at these addresses, I have no idea where to stop.

Comment: Your question appears to be an *XY Problem*. See: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  Both `nm` and `readelf` display human readable listings of the elf object files. Other than relative addresses to make the listing understandable, I'm not sure that "blank spaces" have much significance. What is it you are attempting to use the elf contents for? Also, what hardware is involved?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's true, but I just took the section sizes into consideration. But I guess you're right as I ended up two different address estimations. Anyway, the hardware is Sparc and I'm trying to run the ELF of a simple code for that architecture. I believe I'm having trouble with 'where to end the execution'.

Comment: Eeew, I haven't thought about Sparc Stations since working for RSOC in the late 80's. Each of those tools does a good job dumping the elf sections, headers, etc.., but other than providing relative addresses for purpose of the instruction listing, the spaces don't tell you much. Is there no way to get the source and recompile on Sparc? Where to end execution can be tricky because it can end from just about anywhere in response to an error condition. Is the goal here to attempt to reverse-engineer how the elf file works? That is beyond a short answer and others will have to help there.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The goal isn't to reverse engineer the elf, but I guess it's turning out to be exactly that. The compiler isn't working properly and I'm debugging it. As of now I think the compiler isn't able to figure out the end of the elf. It has conditions to check for address overflow and stuff but it just doesn't know where to stop. I thought if I can find the end of an ELF file based on its size, I can add the necessary condition. Well anyway, thank you!